# jquery jscrollpane container acting like an iframe

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I dont' want it to be an iframe for the jscrollpane container. How would i fix this problem? Right now its acting like an iframe... I'm trying to create content inside the jscrollpane container and shifting it outside of the container (using absolute positioning and negative px values), but it gets cut out from the containers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually jscrollpane setting overflow: hidden on the main container. It is the key style to set custom scroll. So if you need to shift out something, it should be outside of this container.
You can try play with paddings, and try it to be equal to your maximum offset element. Or you can try to set it outside and set listener for scroll event.